# Rails Semantic UI Modal Creating Additional Dom Elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I have a modal that displays validation errors.  My issue is that every time I close out the modal, and trigger it again, it duplicates and I then have to close it twice.

The problem is just like this:
[StackOverflow: PHP Semantic-UI Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166712/semantic-ui-modal)

That solution doesn't work. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the way rails handles partials, or if I'm implementing the modal wrong. I need help understanding what's going on and how I can fix it.

index.html

```
<div class="eight wide stackable column">
  <div id="payee_errors"></div>
</div>
```

error partial:

```
<div class="ui modal">
  <div class="header"><%= pluralize(target.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this  <%= target.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> from being saved:</div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="header">
      There were problems with the following fields:
    </h3>
    <div class="ui list">
      <% target.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <div class="item">
            <%= msg %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui green cancel button">Ok. It won't happen again.     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

create.js.coffee

```
$("#payee_errors").html("<%=escape_javascript(render partial: 'errors' , :locals => {:target => @payee }) %>")
$('.ui .modal').modal('show')
```

**Edit:**

The answer below sent me in the right direction. Here's what I ended up doing.  The only difference between his answer was I had to hide the modal using its `onApprove` callback method.

```
$('.ui.modal').html('')
$("#payee_errors").html("<%=escape_javascript(render partial: 'errors/errors' , :locals => {:target => @payee }) %>")
$('.ui.modal').modal(
  onApprove: ->
    $('.ui.modal').modal 'hide'
    return
).modal 'show'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you close the modal, you are just hiding it without destroying the content you created.

The solution is to clear the div before closing it, like that:

```
$('.ui .modal').html('')
$('.ui .modal').modal('hide')
```

Comment: Your answer sent me in the right direction.  I was trying to use clear, empty or whatever Jquery method I could find.  I never thought of setting the entire modal div to an empty string.  I ended up having to call `hide` from a callback method, that's the only thing I had to do differently.